# LINQ slow even before getting data?

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have following query:

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

var model = new StatusModel();

IQueryable<StatusView> statusViewResult = db.StatusViewList;         

statusViewResult = statusViewResult.Where(p =>
   (query.ClustersSelected.Count == 0 || query.ClustersSelected.Contains(p.Cluster)) &&
   (query.ParkNamesSelected.Count == 0 || query.ParkNamesSelected.Contains(p.ParkName)) &&
   (query.TurbineNumbersSelected.Count == 0 || query.TurbineNumbersSelected.Contains(p.TurbineNumber)) &&
   (query.ModelNamesSelected.Count == 0 || query.ModelNamesSelected.Contains(p.ModelName)) &&
   (query.AlarmLevelSelected.Count == 0 || query.AlarmLevelSelected.Contains(p.AlarmLevel)) &&
   (query.ParametersSelected.Count == 0 || query.ParametersSelected.Contains(p.Parameter)) &&
   (query.TurbineTypesSelected.Count == 0 || query.TurbineTypesSelected.Contains(p.TurbineType)));

sw.Stop();

var d = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
```

So I am not doing any `ToList()` so I shouldn't be querying the database at this moment. However I takes around 2 seconds just for building this query - am I missing something here or is this expected?

Comment: Well we don't know what `query.ClustersSelected` etc are - if you're making database queries within that code, that would slow things down. If not, please provide a [mcve]. Have you used a profiler to work out where the time is going? Have you considered calling `Where` conditionally for each filter, rather than passing in a very large expression tree?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All the query.SomeNameSelected are clean string arrays with maximum of 5 elements. What would be the best approach for profiling this kind of issue?

Comment: We'll I'd run the code in a profiler...

Comment: I tried that but it's more focused on CPU. I tried doing following to get the SQL to see why it is running slow.     using (DB context = new DB(Config.ConnectionString))
            {
                context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s); . Unfortunetly it add a lot of parameters like  WHERE (0 = @p__linq__0) AND (0 = @p__linq__1) AND (0 = @p__linq__2) AND (0 = @p__linq__3) AND (0 = @p__linq__4) AND (0 = @p__linq__5) AND (0 = @p__linq__6). Do you know if you can get the full xml including parameters?

Comment: Well do you have evidence that it's actually *executing* any SQL at the moment? And most profilers are quite capable of showing elapsed time as well as CPU time...

Comment: I was just using the Visual Studio Profiler. I have to dig deeper to figure out to trouble shoot. Thanks for your support its highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it only slow the first time? Isn't it okay on the 2nd pass?  The first time a dbcontext is newed up, it has to build the model (fluent api/data annotations) via the static constructor which often takes a bit.

Comment: Nopes it takes 5 secs. Doing a select in studio management goes very fast.Right now I am looking for a way to get the SQL the EF generates including all the @p__linq_x params.

Comment: A useful tool you can try is LINQPad and then it will show the SQL sent with parameters, I believe.